# Syntax error when declaring a class in PlantUML .puml file

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram, plantuml, puml

I have this .puml code:

```
@startuml

class ClassName {
  // Class members (attributes and methods)
}

participant Object1
participant Object2
participant Object3
participant Object4
participant Object5
participant Object6
control Object7

note left of Object6
  This is a note about the Customer class.
end note

title Sequence Diagram with Decision Blocks

@enduml
```

and I get this error:

[image]

anybody know why I can't declare a class there?

Answer (score 2):

Your diagram is a sequence diagram, and not a class diagram.  In UML, the **lifelines of a sequence diagram correspond to [instances of classifiers](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams.html)** and not to classes.

Moreover, it's not a commonly accepted UML practice to model the full details of a class with all its internals in a sequence diagram.  So plantuml would not know how to render such a mixture.  Therefore it is not accepted in the plantuml language, which only allow a limited number of participant types (e.g.  [Entity-Boundary-Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-control-boundary) which are popular non-standard stereotype), see the [online reference](https://plantuml.com/en/sequence-diagram) in section "Declaring participant"

Here how to relate objects to classes, with `ObjectZ` without specified class, `ObjectX` as  instance of a given class, and  an anonymous object of a given class:

```
participant objectZ
participant "objectX:ClassName"
participant ":ClassName"
```

[image]

The problem with the quotes, is that it is later difficult to use for modelling the messages exchanged, since you alway need to spell the full quote content:

```
"objectX:ClassName" -> ":ClassName"
```

So a practical tip is to make full use of alias enabled by plantuml, to use only a shorter object name later on:

```
participant "objectX:ClassName" as objectX
participant ":ClassName" as ClassName

objectX -> ClassName
```